# Inconveniente con condicionales anidados en Bat

Tags: windows, cmd

Necesito crear un programa que tome la fecha actual y si esa fecha se encuentra entre el día 10 y el 20 del mes, me imprima la fecha del mes pasado en formato YYYYMM (o sea, mes -1).

El código que hice es el siguiente:

```
@echo off &setlocal
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET _test=%date%
SET _month=%_test:~4,2%
SET year=%_test:~10,4%
SET day=%_test:~7,2%

if %day% GTR 10 (

    if %day% LSS 20 (

        IF %_month% EQU 1 (
                set search_month=12
                set /a search_year= %year% -1
        )

        IF %_month% EQU 2 (
                set search_month=01
                set /a search_year= %year%
        )
        IF %_month% EQU 3 (
                set search_month=02
                set /a search_year= %year%
        )

        IF %_month% EQU 4 (
                set search_month=03
                set /a search_year= %year%
        )
        IF %_month% EQU 5 (
            set search_month=04
            set /a search_year= %year%
        )
        IF %_month% EQU 6 (
            set search_month=05
            set /a search_year= %year%
        )

        IF %_month% EQU 7 (
                set search_month=06
                set /a search_year= %year%
        )

        IF %_month% EQU 8 (
                set search_month=07
                set /a search_year= %year%
        )

        IF %_month% EQU 9 (
                set search_month=08
                set /a search_year= %year%
        )

        IF %_month% EQU 10 (
                set search_month=09
                set /a search_year= %year%
        )

        IF %_month% EQU 11 (
                set search_month=10
                set /a search_year= %year%
        )

        IF %_month% EQU 12 (
                set search_month=11
                set /a search_year= %year%
        )

        set /a tosearch = %search_year%%search_month%01
        echo tosearch is %tosearch%

        set /a actualdate = %year%%_month%01
        echo actualdate is %actualdate%


     )
 )
```

El inconveniente que tengo es que, después de ejecutar este programa, ambas variables (actualdate y tosearch) se encuentran vacías.
¿Cuál es el error en el código?

Comment: te refieres a que una vez terminado el programa y regresado al shell, no encuentras dichas variables en el entorno? si ese es tu problema, es debido a que tu programa corre en un entorno local, tal como especificas con  `setlocal`.

Comment: nono, lo que quiero decir que al hacer un echo %actualdate% las variables estan vacias.

Answer (score 1):

veo dos errores en tu código

el primero, que `%date%` es una variable de poco fiar en código BAT. La razón es que %date% devuelve la fecha en un formato configurable, cada usuario puede configurar su sistema para que devuelva la fecha de una forma distinta, con lo que código del tipo `SET year=%date:~10,4%` tiene muchas posibilidades de fallar estrepitosamente.

el segundo es que con `EnabledDelayedExpansion` las variables no se expanden, fuera de los paréntesis, con `%var%` sino con `!var!`

para corregir el primer problema, deberías usar otro método de obtener la fecha. Te recomiendo utilizar WMIC, de una forma parecida a ...

```
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%B IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year ^| findstr /r /v "^$"') DO (     
  echo %%G %%B %%E
)
```

y para corregir el segundo problema, algo así como esto

```
  if %%B GTR 10 (
    if %%B LSS 27 (
      IF %%E EQU 7 (
          set search_month=06
          set /a search_year= %%G
      )
    )
  )
  set /a tosearch = !search_year!!search_month!01
)
echo !tosearch!
```